# How can I clone an object and iterate over one of it's properties?

Tags: javascript, object, promise, clone, bluebird

I'm trying to clone an object within a promise and iterate a property of it.

This seems to work, you get an array of objest where `page_num` is incremented from 2 to 44.

```
var allOptions = _.map(_.range(2, 45), function(page){
  return { body: { action: 'read', page_num: page, page_size: 5 }}
})

Promise.map(allOptions, function(options){
  return Promise.resolve(options).delay(3000)
}).then(console.log)
```

However this example above is creating an object from scratch every time.

When I try to clone an existing object like so I get the behavior described below.

```
var masterOptions = { body: { action: 'read', page_num: 1, page_size: 5 }}

var allOptions = _.map(_.range(2, 45), function(page){
  var options = _.clone(masterOptions)
  options.body.page_num = page
  return options
})

Promise.map(allOptions, function(options){
  return Promise.resolve(options).delay(3000)
}).then(console.log)
```

or

```
Promise.map(_.range(2, 45), function(page){
  var options = _.clone(masterOptions)
  options.body.page_num = page
  return Promise.resolve(options).delay(3000)
}).then(console.log)
```

These do not seem to work, the options object seems to be iterating over the last produced object `{ body: { action: 'read', page_num: 44, page_size: 5 } }` for each iteration.

How can I clone an object and iterate over one of it's properties?

Comment: I believe I fixed this by switching to lodash's [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep).

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with promises/bluebird? Don't you get the same behavior with `console.log(allOptions)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, **Underscore**'s `clone` function isn't **deep**.

This means that each property of the object you're cloning will be a **new** variable, but that variable will be populated simply by **copying** the content of the corresponding original one.

That is actually mentioned in the documentation for [**Underscore**'s `clone` function (link)](http://underscorejs.org/#clone). Here's what is said:

> Create a shallow-copied clone of the provided *plain* **object**. Any nested
>   objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.

---

So, as you guessed, it seems that there's no out-of-the-box *deep copy function* in **Underscore** right now. Using [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) as you mentioned in your comment will indeed resolve your issue :)